# ADODB.Connection with Excel to Access database performance improvement

Tags: performance, excel, ms-access, adodb, recordset

We have created a access database and one developer has created a function into excel to access the data from this database.
The connection is done via ADDB.Connection. 
The formula returns 1 figure which is the sum of volumes in the Access database taking into consideration some of the parameters. 
When we run the formula in one cell it works perfectly, but as our reports contain more than one cell with this formula (about 160 cells). The reports are really slow to run.

One of our expert in Access check the database and he does not see any mistake in the way it has been built.

Would anybody have an idea how to sort this?
What about librairies we should tick in Excel to have it working properly?
We work today on MS Excel & Access 2003 (I know we are out of age) but I would have the opportunity to upgrade to Excel & Access 2007 (what an progress ;-) ), would it help?

This is the detail of our vba code in Excel

```
'The function is called GetMarketData
Function GetMarketData(Optional ProductLine As String, Optional country As String, Optional CountryGroup As String, Optional Market As String, Optional startMonth As Long, Optional endMonth As Long, Optional Brand As String, Optional Model As String, Optional Segment As String, Optional EngineSegment As String)

'This is the declaration of variables
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rsQuery As ADODB.Recordset
Dim i As Integer
Dim iCount As Integer
Dim resVar As Integer
Dim query1 As String, query2 As String, query3 As String, query4 As String
Dim parametres As String, param1 As String, param2 As String, param3 As String, param4     As String, param5 As String, param6 As String, param7 As String, param8 As String, param9 As String, param10 As String


' Query cut in 3 parts (will be regrouped later on)
query1 = "SELECT Sum(T_MARKET.Volume) "
query2 = "FROM T_COUNTRY_GROUP INNER JOIN (T_TIME_PERIOD INNER JOIN (T_SELECTED_MARKET INNER JOIN (T_SEGMENT INNER JOIN (T_PRODUCT_LINE INNER JOIN ((T_BRAND INNER JOIN T_MODEL ON T_BRAND.ID_Brand = T_MODEL.FK_Brand) INNER JOIN ((T_COUNTRY INNER JOIN T_MARKET ON T_COUNTRY.ID_Country = T_MARKET.FK_Country) INNER JOIN ((T_ENGINE_SEGMENT INNER JOIN T_PRODUCT ON T_ENGINE_SEGMENT.ID_Engine_Segment = T_PRODUCT.FK_Engine_Segment) " _
         & "INNER JOIN T_SEGMENT_FINAL ON T_ENGINE_SEGMENT.ID_Engine_Segment = T_SEGMENT_FINAL.FK_Engine_Segment) ON (T_PRODUCT.ID_Product = T_MARKET.FK_Product) AND (T_COUNTRY.ID_Country = T_SEGMENT_FINAL.FK_Country)) ON T_MODEL.ID_Model = T_PRODUCT.FK_Model) ON T_PRODUCT_LINE.ID_Product_Line = T_SEGMENT_FINAL.FK_Product_Line) ON (T_SEGMENT.ID_Segment = T_SEGMENT_FINAL.FK_Segment) AND (T_SEGMENT.ID_Segment = T_PRODUCT.FK_Segment)) ON T_SELECTED_MARKET.ID_Selected_Market = T_SEGMENT_FINAL.FK_Selected_Market) ON T_TIME_PERIOD.ID_Period = T_MARKET.FK_Time_period) ON T_COUNTRY_GROUP.ID_Country_Groupe = T_COUNTRY.FK_Country_Group "
query3 = "WHERE ("

    param1 = "((T_PRODUCT_LINE.Product_Line)='" & ProductLine & "')"
    param2 = " AND ((T_COUNTRY.Country)='" & country & "')"
    param3 = " AND ((T_COUNTRY_GROUP.Country_Group)='" & CountryGroup & "')"
    param4 = " AND ((T_SELECTED_MARKET.Selected_Market)='" & Market & "')"
    param5 = " AND ((T_TIME_PERIOD.Cal_FullDate)>=" & startMonth & ")"
    param6 = " AND ((T_TIME_PERIOD.Cal_FullDate)<=" & endMonth & ")"
    param7 = " AND ((T_BRAND.Brand)='" & Brand & "')"
    param8 = " AND ((T_MODEL.Model)='" & Model & "')"
    param9 = " AND ((T_SEGMENT.Segment)='" & Segment & "')"
    param10 = " AND ((T_ENGINE_SEGMENT.Engine_Segment)='" & EngineSegment & "')"

    parametres = param1

    If country <> "" Then
        parametres = parametres & param2
    End If
    If CountryGroup <> "" Then
        parametres = parametres & param3
    End If
    If Market <> "" Then
        parametres = parametres & param4
    End If
    If startMonth <> 0 Then
        parametres = parametres & param5
    End If
    If endMonth <> 0 Then
        parametres = parametres & param6
    End If
    If Brand <> "" Then
        parametres = parametres & param7
    End If
    If Model <> "" Then
        parametres = parametres & param8
    End If
    If Segment <> "" Then
        parametres = parametres & param9
    End If
    If EngineSegment <> "" Then
        parametres = parametres & param10
    End If


query4 = ");"

'Connexion with the Access database
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & URL_Base & ";"

'Open a recordset based on the query
Set rsQuery = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rsQuery.ActiveConnection = con
rsQuery.Open query1 & query2 & query3 & parametres & query4

' Give back the value from the query
GetMarketData = rsQuery.Fields(0).Value

'Clear variables
rsQuery.Close
Set rsQuery = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
```

End Function

Comment: I am going to paraphrase your question, please let me know if this is correct. You have the function listed in Excel. The function works. You have a report in Excel which calls the function 160 times, once for each cell the function is placed in, and the reports are slow because of this. Are you asking how the same information can be obtained faster?

Comment: Exactly!But I would also had that it seems that the speed depends also on the level of detail of the query. the more parameters we have the quicker it goes. If it is a large query (only one parameter for example) it takes more time.

Comment: That makes sense. The more parameters you are selecting by, the fewer rows that ADO has to return for the sum, and the faster it appears. You're passing param 5 and 6 as seperate numbers to represent dates? If you will always have both 5 and 6 you might try ...cal_fulldate BETWEEN " & startMonth & " and " & endMonth. If you're passing an acutal date check that you're table is using a date data type and bookend the param with '#'. Also check that each field that you're using as a param have an index applied in the source table.

Comment: You can also try setting the cusor type to static and the record lock type to read only. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675544(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Two suggestions:  1. Get rid of the inner joins; either by adding logic that would substitute for them in VBA or finding some other way.  2a. Redesign the query and function so that it is an array function so there is only one call to the database instead of 160 calls.  2b same premise but instead of making it an array function store cached data in one or more global variables and have the function check the cache before actually executing the query.  The approach in 2b will be pretty tricky I'm currently working on this approach myself.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, DAO is much faster than ADODB used with MS Access. This is tested in Excel. Note that `Like *` does not include Nulls, so this is only an example. You can also build temporary queries in VBA and assign parameters to them, but they are likely to be slower than a stored query.

```
Function DAOMarket(Optional ProductLine As String, Optional country As String, _
Optional CountryGroup As String, Optional Market As String, Optional startMonth As Long, _
Optional endMonth As Long, Optional Brand As String, _
Optional Model As String, Optional Segment As String, Optional EngineSegment As String)

'Reference: Microsoft Office x.x Access Database Engine Object Library
Dim ws As DAO.Workspace
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim sDb As String
Dim sSQL As String
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

sDb = "Z:\Docs\Test.accdb"

Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set db = ws.OpenDatabase(sDb)

''A stored query, see below
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("GetMarket")

qdf.Parameters![@ProductLine] = IIf(ProductLine & "" = "", "*", ProductLine)
qdf.Parameters![@Country] = IIf(country & "" = "", "*", country)
qdf.Parameters![@Country_Group] = IIf(CountryGroup & "" = "", "*", CountryGroup)
qdf.Parameters![@Selected_market] = IIf(Market & "" = "", "*", Market)
qdf.Parameters![@CalStart] = IIf(startMonth & "" = "", 1, startMonth)
qdf.Parameters![@CalEnd] = IIf(endMonth & "" = "", 12, endMonth)
qdf.Parameters![@Brand] = IIf(Brand & "" = "", "*", Brand)
qdf.Parameters![@Model] = IIf(Model & "" = "", "*", Model)
qdf.Parameters![@Segment] = IIf(Segment & "" = "", "*", Segment)
qdf.Parameters![@Engine_Segment] = IIf(EngineSegment & "" = "", "*", EngineSegment)
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
DAOMarket = rs.Fields(0)
End Function
```

SQL

```
SELECT SUM([t_market].[volume]) AS MarketVolume
FROM   ((t_selected_market
         INNER JOIN (t_product_line
                     INNER JOIN ((t_brand
                                  INNER JOIN t_model
                                          ON t_brand.id_brand =
                                 t_model.fk_brand)
                                 INNER JOIN ((t_engine_segment
                                              INNER JOIN t_product
                                                      ON
                                              t_engine_segment.id_engine_segment
                                              =
                                              t_product.fk_engine_segment)
                                             INNER JOIN t_segment_final
                                                     ON
                                             t_engine_segment.id_engine_segment
                                             =
                                             t_segment_final.fk_engine_segment)
                                         ON t_model.id_model =
                                            t_product.fk_model)
                             ON t_product_line.id_product_line =
                                t_segment_final.fk_product_line)
                 ON t_selected_market.id_selected_market =
                    t_segment_final.fk_selected_market)
        INNER JOIN t_segment
                ON t_segment_final.fk_segment = t_segment.id_segment)
       INNER JOIN (t_country_group
                   INNER JOIN (t_time_period
                               INNER JOIN (t_country
                                           INNER JOIN t_market
                                                   ON t_country.id_country =
                                                      t_market.fk_country)
                                       ON t_time_period.id_period =
                                          t_market.fk_time_period)
                           ON t_country_group.id_country_groupe =
                              t_country.fk_country_group)
               ON t_product.id_product = t_market.fk_product
WHERE  ( ( ( t_product_line.product_line ) LIKE [@productline] )
         AND ( ( t_country.country ) LIKE [@country] )
         AND ( ( t_country_group.country_group ) LIKE [@country_group] )
         AND ( ( t_selected_market.selected_market ) LIKE [@selected_market] )
         AND ( ( t_time_period.cal_fulldate ) BETWEEN [@calstart] AND [@calend]
             )
         AND ( ( t_brand.brand ) LIKE [@brand] )
         AND ( ( t_model.model ) LIKE [@model] )
         AND ( ( t_segment.segment ) LIKE [@segment] )
         AND ( ( t_engine_segment.engine_segment ) LIKE [@engine_segment] ) );
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you. We have reviewed the Access base structure and we have discovered that the primary key in the Access database are ID-numbers (created with Auto_number). We also saw that the indexes where applied on these ID_numbers. As we do in the excel file use parameters to get a value and those parameters are text, we thought we had to rebuild the Access database using parameters indexed (in Text) instead of numbers.